# How to collect output of several commands into one file in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to collect Git information into file and am doing

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND git log -1 --format=full && echo "Modified files:" && git ls-files -m
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

or

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND git log -1 --format=full 
    COMMAND echo "Modified files:"
    COMMAND git ls-files -m
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

And in both cases don't see full content. In first case I see empty file and in second -- only output of last command.

How to gather all in one file?

Comment: Although you're using Git commands here, in the end, this is really just a question about how to use CMake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in first case I see empty file

Sure - no shell is used, and `&&` is invalid argument to `git`, the command fails. See documentation `No intermediate shell is used, so shell operators such as > are treated as normal arguments`.

> in second -- only output of last command.

Sure - see documentation `Commands are executed concurrently as a pipeline, with the standard output of each process piped to the standard input of the next`. `git ... | echo ... | git ...` will only output the last one - `git` and `echo` ignore standard input.

---

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND sh -c "
       git log -1 --format=full && 
       echo \"Modified files:\" &&
       git ls-files -m"
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log1"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```

or

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND git log -1 --format=full 
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log1"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
execute_process(
    COMMAND echo ...
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log2"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
execute_process(
    COMMAND git ...
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log3"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E cat git_log1 git_log2 git_log3
    OUTPUT_FILE "git_log"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
```